# How can I add padding to html dropdownlist?

Tags: html, css

I want to add padding to the options of html "select" tag.

I try to add it in the style property of "select" and "option" and it doesn't work in IE.

What can I do?

Comment: what are you trying to do? why do you want to pad the select options?

Comment: I want to add some space to the left and right sides of select options to make it look better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, I hate to sound all 1990s, but would simply pre- and app-ending a space to the option text be acceptable for your desired goals?

Comment: +1 vote: This is the best solution given that the OP wants to just add some space to the left and right, and if he does not want to spend a couple of hours implementing custom dropdown.

Comment: Please don't do that. That prevents selecting options from a list by typing. It also breaks auto-fill. This is particular impedance to users with accessibility requirements.

Comment: **Another solution which works in all browser**, is adding `&nbsp;` to first Option in select list check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752/how-do-i-put-a-space-character-before-option-text-in-a-html-select-element) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828697/how-to-retain-spaces-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-razor-views), Hope helps.

Answer (score 8):

It is difficult to style a drop down box cross browser. To get any sort of control, you'll need to code a replacement one in JavaScript. Be warned, however:

- Remember that the user may have difficulty using your drop down - take usabilty into account
- Replace a select element with JS - this is an accessibility issue (and also allows users without JS support to use the form input)

Answer (score 3):

The following works, in FF3+ and Midori (and presumably other Webkit browsers):

```
select
        {width: 14em;
        margin: 0 1em;
        text-indent: 1em;
        line-height: 2em;}

select *    {width: 14em;
        padding: 0 1em;
        text-indent: 0;
        line-height: 2em;}
```

The width is to allow enough room in the displayed `select` box when not active, the margin does what it always does, `text-indent` is used to feign padding between the left boundary of the select box and the inner-text. `line-height` is just to allow vertical spacing.

I can't comment on its use in IE, I'm afraid, so if anyone could feed back -or adapt- to suit that'd be good.

It's worth noting that the drop-down part of the select (`select *`) isn't affected outside of FF3 for me, for whatever reason, so if that was the question you wanted answering, I apologise for offering nothing new.

Demo at: http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/select-styling.html

Answer (score 2):

**Create a class for the SELECT**

```
.listBox{
   width: 200px; 
   ...etc
}
```

Now define the Css for the options of the SELECT

```
 .listBox option{
     padding:4px;
    ...etc
  }
```

*Tested on IE 10*

Answer (score -3):

CSS:

```
option{
 padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: The only browser in which this works is Firefox. Safari, Chrome, and Opera all take no notice of it.

Answer (score -3):

I couldnt get this to work with padding or spacing for some reason. I went with a jQuery solution that looks like this:

```
$(document).click(function(){  
  $('#selector option').each(function(){  
    $(this).html("&nbsp;&nbsp;"+$(this).text());  
  });  
});
```