# ASP.NET MVC Razor render SelectList without encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I get my select list to render without HTML coding

```
@{
    var noiceList = new SelectList(new[] { new {ID = "", Name = ""}, 
                                   new {ID = "y", Name = "Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;after3Space"}, 
                 "ID", "Name"); 
 }
 @Html.DropDownList("noice", @noiceList )
```

rendered

```
..
<option value="y">Yes&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;3Space</option>
...
```

How do I get it to instead render

```
<option value="y">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;after3Space</option>
```

Comment: why not just use HTML - `<select id="noice"><option value="y">Yes&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;3Space</option></select>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retain spaces in DropDownList - ASP.net MVC Razor views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828697/how-to-retain-spaces-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-razor-views)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this in C# is to use `\xA0` instead of `&nbsp;` so you can avoid all that extra code.

Credit goes to this answer: [How to retain spaces in DropDownList - ASP.net MVC Razor views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828697/how-to-retain-spaces-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-razor-views)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this behavior is not built-in.  The `Html.DropDownList` method (and most other `HtmlHelper` methods) always escapes all input text.

#### Workaround

There are workarounds, however.  For example, you could create your own HtmlHelper method that allows unescaped HTML.

But if your needs are as simple as your example, here's a simple workaround:
Use a placeholder, such as `|`, and then replace it with `&nbsp;`, like this:

```
@{
    var noiceList = new SelectList(new[] { new {ID = "", Name = ""}, 
                                   new {ID = "y", Name = "Yes|||after3Space"}, 
                 "ID", "Name"); 
 }
 @Html.Raw(Html.DropDownList("noice", @noiceList).ToString().Replace("|", "&nbsp;"))
```

Note, you could also create a simple extension method to really reduce the amount of code required:

```
 public static HtmlString Replace(this HtmlString input, string findAll, string replaceWith) {
    return new HtmlString(input.ToString().Replace(findAll, replaceWith));
 }
```

This simplifies your Html code to:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("noice", @noiceList).Replace("|", "&nbsp;")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Razor always outputs entity-encoded html. You should be able to call (VS is updating on my machine right now, so I can't do a quick test) `Html.Raw()` in this context, like so:

```
var noiceList = new SelectList(new[] { new {ID = "", Name = ""}, 
                               new {ID = "y", Name = Html.Raw("Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;after3Space")}, 
             "ID", "Name");
```

**EDIT: This does not work.**

Comment: Unfortunately, the `SelectList` produces a list of `SelectListItem`s, which uses a regular old `string` for `Name` and `Value`.  So, this won't work :(

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, it wouldn't work.  Like I said, I couldn't test it because VS was updating at the time.

Comment: I've been wondering if a future version of MVC will include support for nested HTML like this -- perhaps `SelectListItem.Name` could be a `HtmlString` instead?  However, I don't think this is a "pretty" solution, because it should only be used for simple markup.