# Remove left indentation or unknown padding from HTML select element options

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a Registration Form and I am having issues left aligning `input[type="text"] placeholder` and my "pseudo" placeholder for a `<select>` element. I want the input[type="text"] placeholder to be left aligned flush with the "pseudo" placeholder for a `<select>`.

I used the word "pseudo" placeholder for a select HTML element because there is no placeholder for a select HTML element and what is being displayed instead of a placeholder is the first option in the select.

You can see in the screenshot there is a select HTML element with a first `<option>` text of "Country". There is also another select element with the first option text being "HOW SOON DO YOU WANT YOUR BOOK?".

Both these select elements have an indentation to them, compared to the input[type="text"] placeholder text and I cannot left align exactly to the input[type="text"] placeholder text.

[image]

```css
input[type="text"].couture-input-underline,
input[type="password"].couture-input-underline,
input[type="number"].couture-input-underline,
select.couture-input-underline
{
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 0px solid #7f7f7f;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-match-placeholder{
  color: #ACACAC;
}

select option
{
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<select class="couture-input-underline text-match-placeholder">
  <option value>Choose</option>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
 </select>
<input type="text" class="couture-input-underline" placeholder="Text Box One" />
```

Comment: What you want might not be possible at all, because even if you line them up beautifully it will only be beautiful [on **your** browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare)

Comment: As above poster suggests, select styling shows up differently on each browser. I would try a javascript plugin to style the select so that it is consistent cross-browser.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27006710/2074346

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Padding in Select Boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to recreate it and I've found the "bug" only on Firefox.
If this is the case then, what happens here is the declaration

```
 select > option {
 -moz-padding-start: 3px;
 }
```

that is found in the user agent styles.
[See here how to inspect that](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/inspect-user-agent-styles-in-firefox-devtools)

Nonetheless, if you overwrite it for `select > option`, in your CSS, it doesn't work.

```
 /** IF you add the following
     in your CSS, it won't solve 
     the problem
 **/

 select > option {
 -moz-padding-start: 0 !important;
 }
```

*My guess* is that the element actually showing the padding is a "ghost" element that is a duplicate of that `<option>` element and as such it is not targeted by your css.

This is a very ugly fix for that

```
input[type="text"].couture-input-underline,
input[type="password"].couture-input-underline,
input[type="number"].couture-input-underline,
select.couture-input-underline
{
  padding-left: 3px;
}
select.couture-input-underline {

  -moz-padding-start: 0px;
}
```

[And you can see it here](http://codepen.io/kuzeko/details/WwEVyG/)

This will basically add `3px` left to every input, on FF this will make the option indented `6px` , so we reset it for the `select` element only.