# How to remove unwanted padding on styled select in IE11/Windows 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, internet-explorer-11

The select is hidden behind the text with `opacity: 0` and will be opened normally with a click. My problem is, that the options got unwanted padding on top and bottom of the list in IE11 on Windows 8:

[image]

The padding comes from the changed height of the select. But I need it as large as the text to open it by click. I don't think there's any opportunity to reduce the select in height and open it with Javascript?

Running example:

```css
div {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="test" id="test">
    <option>Lorem</option>
    <option>Ipsum</option>
    <option>Dolor</option>
    <option>Sit</option>
    <option>Amet</option>
  </select>
  <span>Open select</span>
</div>
```

Same problem occurs on the [jQuery-Customselect-Plugin](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/), which uses the same technique:

[image]

Also, I opened an issue on the plugin:
https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect/issues/110

Comment: Tried `padding: 0px;`? No IE here =/ . Maybe [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20appearance) and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) may change your mind into using the native select element in favor of [select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/)

Comment: Yep, I tried anything. Don't want to use a replacement of the select.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
select {
  /* changes */
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="test" id="test">
    <option>Lorem</option>
    <option>Ipsum</option>
    <option>Dolor</option>
    <option>Sit</option>
    <option>Amet</option>
  </select>
  <span>Open select</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The padding is still visible on IE11, therefore this is not working.

Comment: @roNn23 , does padding even work at all in IE? It seems like it doesn't, because that solution works fine in chrome.

Comment: Yeah, but I've asked for IE11/Win8.

Comment: @roNn233 if it doesn't work on IE11, than your goal might not be possible. The options are the only thing with padding on them, so that has to be what you remove padding from. If that doesn't work in IE, than padding might just be one of the many things that IE can't work with. Do you know if padding works in IE11? My IDEs think that IE11 shouldn't be used for testing, and I haven't figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove padding from ie11 selects alone. Your best bet is to remove them all the selects and use css classes for uniquely styled ones.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a padding-top 0 px. Im not using ie11, but this could help.

```
select {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  padding-top:0px;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to inspect that extra padding in dev tools? Myb it`s a margin not a padding.

Comment: Yep. And you can't inspect it. But it is indeed a padding, I tried to set it. But you can't overwrite it. I think this is a bug in IE/Win8, more or less...

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it on my own with some JS magic:

[image]

Now the size of the select isn't increased by CSS. Instead it is bound to the mouse movement on the element. So the padding in the option list is fine and the select is opening by clicking at all position on the styled span.

I've added an example (the green one), where you can see the technique behind.

```js
function onMouseMove(event) {
  var $div = $(this);
  var divOffset = $div.offset();
  var $select = $(this).find('select');
  var relX = event.pageX - divOffset.left;
  var relY = event.pageY - divOffset.top;

  $select.css('top', relY - 5);
  
  if(
    relY > $div.height() ||
    relX > $div.width() ||
    relY < 0 ||
    relX < 0
  ) {
    $select.css('top', 'auto');
  }
}

function onSelectClick(event) {
  if($(event.target).is('select') === false) {
    return;
  }
  
  $(this).addClass('select-open');
}

function onSelectBlur() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('select-open');
}

function onSelectChange() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('select-open');
}

function onBodyClick(event) {  
  if($(event.target).is('select')) {
    return;
  }
  
  $('div.select-open').removeClass('select-open');
}

$('body')
  .on('mousemove', 'div:not(.select-open)', onMouseMove)
  .on('click', 'div:not(.select-open) select', onSelectClick)
  .on('change', 'select', onSelectChange)
  .on('blur', 'select', onSelectBlur)
;
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.visible-technique {
  background: green;
}

.visible-technique select {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="test" id="test">
    <option selected>Lorem</option>
    <option>Ipsum</option>
    <option>Dolor</option>
    <option>Sit</option>
    <option>Amet</option>
  </select>
  <span>Open select</span>
</div>

<div class="visible-technique">
  <select name="test" id="test">
    <option selected>Lorem</option>
    <option>Ipsum</option>
    <option>Dolor</option>
    <option>Sit</option>
    <option>Amet</option>
  </select>
  <span>Open select</span>
</div>
```

You can play with it on Codepen, too: http://codepen.io/roNn23/pen/OXyagN

**Update**

Sadly, I have to admit, that this bug can't be solved with this workaroud. The problem is, that there is no event to detect whether the select is closed. So you have sometimes to click two times to toggle the status and this isn't understandable for the user. So in my opinion, we have to live with this IE-bug when customizing the select. Otherwise you could use a select replacement script, but I wouldn't do this, because this is too much overhead for such a little problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can still work with the `:active` state. Example uses `padding`:

```
select {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

select:active {
  padding: 0;
}
```

This may require some rigid positioning of the select element so it doesn't move when shrunk and made active, but that should be no issue.

Comment: It is working exactly as presented, just retested on IE11. Please specify the issue better.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just need a CSS reset like this:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Just put it above the others (or something call it first). It will give you a fresh pallet and wouldn't conflict with your next codes. Each browser has it's own preferences, so it would be nice (if you just want) to have a zero-like thing at start and no more need to do some/much *"magic tricks"*.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't gonna help.

Answer (score -1):

Select is an html element that is rendered by browser. If you dont like the select component that browsers give you, you can design your own dropdown component using html, css, javascript.

Like what Telerik did

[Telerik Kendo UI DropdownList](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index)

Comment: I don't want to use a replacement, because there are a lot of usability issues for the user. Especially on mobile... For this reason I want to stick to native Elements which are styled over. This is working in all browsers, except the IE11 on Windows 8.

Comment: If you just use javascript, css and html, then you will get the same result in all modern browsers including mobile browser. Have you tried kendo ui dropdownlist in a mobile browser before you wrote a comment?

Comment: This could be but is not the intention of the question.

Answer (score -1):

as i have gone through this problem before

and here i found very good reference link for that posted by Jerreck for the question

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes)

This extra **whitespace** is added by the browser's rendering engine. Form element rendering is inconsistent across browsers, and in this case is not determined by CSS.Take a look at this article from Mozilla explaining some ways to mitigate select box incosistency, then you might read this article from Smashing Magazine about styling form elements (be sure to check out the comments and the problems people have had with selects).

**so for this i suggest that you might use any third party widget for select options for better UI consistency for select-option component it's my personal opinion. you can find widgets and plugins.**

> Note :  one interesting fact for this padding is the height given to the  this blank padding is appearing only when if you give height more than default height given by browser(IE) if you don't it will not add a padding at top and bottom
>
> **For Example :: if you give "60px" height then those padding will be 30px on top and 30px bottom  i have marked this is just puts text of the  tag in this.**

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to use some replacement techniques. Your link is very helpful, but it's only helping, when styling the select directly. In this case here, I'm just increasing the height of the hidden select to make it clickable. But this results in a padding on the options list.

Comment: @roNn23 so exactly you want to remove space from top and bottom right .?

Comment: @roNn23 hi as i said that increasing the height of the hidden select will make this padding available on front end side have you analyze that ./??

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the height of your select-element. 
The first option of your option-list overlays with the visible select-text in IE11. The height of the selectbox generates a "padding", because the selectbox text is vertical middle aligned.

If you remove the height when the selectbox is active you shouldn't have a padding anymore.

```
select:active, select:focus {
    height: auto;
}
```

EDIT:
In Win8 the selectbox loses the active-state on click so I added :focus - works for me :)

https://jsfiddle.net/s01xh3g5/1/

[Selectbox height/"padding" culprit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygR3m.png)

Comment: That's so far the best answer, but also not perfect. Same as in my JS powered solution: When you open the select and click elsewhere, the optionlist disappears, but the focus is still set. Because of this, you have to click twice to re-open the select again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37704711/907420

Answer (score -3):

Please try to set **selected** for the first option.

```html
<select>
    <option selected>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope, this changes nothing.