# remove space in select box

Tags: html, css

I have a few input fields in a form. I gave them all a padding of 5px but the select boxes seemingly have an additional space inside. It's not caused by padding, margin or text-indent. Text alignment is left. Is there a way to get rid of this?

[image]

Here follows my code. At the bottom is a link to the fiddle.

CSS

```
input[type=text],
select {
    padding:5px;
}
select {
    border:solid 1px #555;
    padding:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Test1</option>
        <option>Test2</option>
        <option>Test3</option>
        <option>Test4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" value="Test" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64ppa5f5/

PS:

I also shecked the zoom and it's 100%.

Comment: Please provide code where your problem is reproducable.

Comment: have you tried to add negative margin-left:-5px; ?

Comment: setting negative margin only moves the entire select-box to the left.

Comment: try thi  style="border: none;background-color: white;"

Comment: only removes the border but the space remains

Comment: You cannot control this with the classic select tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has something todo with the browser rendering itself. See this answer on same question for more informations: [Text Padding in Select Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes)

In summary, you should not do this or not common.

Comment: Thank you, that article exactly describes the effect i'm seeing. Too bad it's that way tho :(

Comment: Yeah you can try @Jeni solution, but it is not save that it will produce the expected result everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

The padding you are seeing is coming from the browser specific stylesheet. To remove space in select box, add the following style.

```
input[type=text],
 select {
   padding:5px;
 }

 select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance : none;
    border:solid 1px #555;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
 }
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes?rq=1)

Comment: Hi i tried the appearance properties but unfortunally it does remove everything but that annoying bit of space :). Reading one of the suggested links it's obviously it can't be removed and i have to use a workaround ..