# Align the text inside a drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text inside a drop down menu in a table cell with other text contents in adjacent table cells.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            .mimicTable{
                display: table;
                border-spacing: 1em;
            }
            .mimicRow{
                display: table-row;
            }
            .mimicCell{
                display: table-cell;
            }
            .mimicRadio{
                background-color: inherit;
                color: inherit;
                width: initial !important;
                padding: 0em !important;
                text-align: left !important;
                text-indent: 0px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .mimicRadio option{
                background-color: grey !important;
                border-color: grey !important;
            }
        </style>
        <main class="form">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <center><p class="whiteGrey font35"> Enter Buying Rate </p></center>
                <br><br>
                <div class="mimicTable">
                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">Coin Type :</div> 
                        <div class="mimicCell">
                            <select name='coin_type'>
                                <option value="Select_Coin">Select Coin</option>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($_SESSION['biscuits']['coin_list'] as $coin)
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value='".$coin."'>".$coin."</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">
                            <select class="mimicRadio" name="buy_type">
                                <option value="coin_buy">Coins</option>
                                <option value="currency_buy">Currency ($)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mimicCell"><input type="text" class="mimicRadioValue" required pattern="[0-9.]{1,}" name="buy_type_value" placeholder="Quantity to buy in Coins"></input></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">Buying Rate ($) :</div>
                        <div class="mimicCell"><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" name="buy_rate" placeholder="Buying rate / USD ($)"></input></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">Extra Message :</div>
                        <div class="mimicCell"><textarea name="espec" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ._$@#₦]{0,100}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Optional Message"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="glassButton" name="buy" value="Buy"></input>
            </form>
        </main> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is an image description:

[image: current state and expected out come]

In case your wondering this is only a minimal verifiable code/example in the complete css they are no borders or box lines round the drop down menu.

I have tried a lot of tricks with css and JavaScript's to manipulate the Dom and archive desired outcome but it seems that am still missing something.

Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Most likely the dropdown has some padding on the left. See how much that padding is and you can add a negative margin-left to that so it cancels out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bump that select element over using `margin`. Try this. I just set `margin: 0 0 0 -10px;`.

```css
.mimicTable{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 1em;
}
.mimicRow{
    display: table-row;
}
.mimicCell{
    display: table-cell;
}
.mimicRadio{
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    width: initial !important;
    padding: 0em !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    text-indent: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}
.mimicRadio option{
    background-color: grey !important;
    border-color: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<main class="form">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <center><p class="whiteGrey font35"> Enter Buying Rate </p></center>
                <br><br>
                <div class="mimicTable">
                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">Coin Type :</div> 
                        <div class="mimicCell">
                            <select name='coin_type'>
                                <option value="Select_Coin">Select Coin</option>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($_SESSION['biscuits']['coin_list'] as $coin)
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value='".$coin."'>".$coin."</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">
                            <select class="mimicRadio" name="buy_type">
                                <option value="coin_buy">Coins</option>
                                <option value="currency_buy">Currency ($)</option>
                                <option value="">Another option</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mimicCell"><input type="text" class="mimicRadioValue" required pattern="[0-9.]{1,}" name="buy_type_value" placeholder="Quantity to buy in Coins"></input></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">Buying Rate ($) :</div>
                        <div class="mimicCell"><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" name="buy_rate" placeholder="Buying rate / USD ($)"></input></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mimicRow">
                        <div class="mimicCell">Extra Message :</div>
                        <div class="mimicCell"><textarea name="espec" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ._$@#₦]{0,100}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Optional Message"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="glassButton" name="buy" value="Buy"></input>
            </form>
        </main>
```

Comment: you've just proved that i need to get some sleep :( why didn't i think of that of all the many unnecessary css i applied. Thanks

Comment: @BobbyAxe It happens =)

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in another question.

[remove space in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994982/remove-space-in-select-box)

[Text Padding in Select Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes)

In both conclusions they really suggest that you shouldn't do it. Its browser specified.

Comment: Exactly why i needed a cross browser solution thanks for your answer i did pick up a trick or two ;)