# Select form element inner text spacing

Tags: html, css

I found this inconsistent behaviour on the select element between -webkit and other browsers. The spacing for the text inside the element isn't consistent with the other input elements. (See example). The selects have an extra **~2px of spacing on the left**. Thus not aligning horizontally with the input element above.

**Chrome** works fine, the text in the elements aligns up horizontally.

[image: Chrome select]

**Firefox** Does not align perfectly horizontally with the input above.

[image: Firefox select]

The padding on the elements is the same. Only this spacing I can't explain exists in the select elements other then on -webkit browsers. I've checked it in:

- Safari (no padding aligns fine)
- Chrome (no padding aligns fine)
- Firefox
- Edge
- IE11

FF, Edge and IE11 all have that (for me) unexplainable spacing. There is no text-indent, no nothing that I could find that explains this extra space.

Here is my (simplified) css for the input and select

```css
html {
    font-size: 93.75%;
    line-height: 2;
    min-height: 100%;
    webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form
{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 30px;
  max-width: 250px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.form__group + .form__group
{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 6.5px 14px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    line-height: inherit;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 3rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

select {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-padding-end: 29px !important;
    -webkit-padding-start: 14px !important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 6.5px 29px 6.5px 14px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #484A4E;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 3rem;
    background-size: 30px 50px;
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSdub25lJyB2aWV3Q…lsZT0nZmlsbDojREZFNEVDOycgcG9pbnRzPScxNSwxNyAxMCwyMiAyMCwyMicvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="form__group">
    <input type="text" name="example-input" value="" placeholder="Example input" />
  </div>
  <div class="form__group">
    <select name="example-select">
      <option value="">Example select</option>
      <option value="example">Example select item</option>
      <option value="another">Another one</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 08 / 2018**

After some more headache and searching the web I found two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994982/remove-space-in-select-box) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes) that seem to "answer" my question. The answer is just as I thought inconsistency in browser rendering. No simple css way to fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: In your example images, where's that "unexplainable" space? Both the images are pretty much looking same for me. `:|`

Comment: They both have the same height and same width I don't find anything odd here

Comment: There is like a ~2px space on the left of the text in the select. They don't align nicely on the left. Although having the same spacing. Will update my question to better clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the basic guideline.

```
* {box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0;margin: 0;}
```

Comment: sorry but how does this solve the problem at hand, when trying your solution the problem still persist. Adding `padding: 0; margin: 0;` with the * selector doesn't help because the padding and margin are set on the form elements. The text inside the select element (to my knowledge) is not a html element on itself (like a span or something) so applying * { ... } doesn't influence the inner text only the select element itself (although that offcource changes the position of the text inside, it isn't clarifying the problem at hand).

Comment: I had seen in Mozilla browser there is showing 2px of the input in the input. if your still not fixed please share both browser screen short.

Comment: after applying your fix in a fiddle it still happened. Look at my original question for screenshots showing the "working alignment and spacing" in Chrome and the faulty one in Firefox. You can open this fiddle in FF (with your solution) and still see the problem of the 2px left spacing in comparison to the input element above. [https://jsfiddle.net/hdcgvs2z/](https://jsfiddle.net/hdcgvs2z/). Opening the fiddle in Chrome/Safari shows the correct alignment of the text inside the form elements.

Comment: This is space is the default for the Firefox browser. If you want to remove you for firefox you can use.
 I have update on the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tushar9/hdcgvs2z/1/