# Vertical align and use padding in Select Input Field

Tags: html, css, forms, select, input

Hi there I am trying to build a form with inputfieled that has overlayerd labels.

The problem is i want to add padding to the content of the input field to correctly align the value of the field. this works for my Regular text input fields but not for select input field.

Can someone tell me why it is not working?

Best way to show is looking at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrcdzbu/): https://jsfiddle.net/pmrcdzbu/

```html
<div class="inputgroup">
            <select class="input filled" id="dropdown">
                <option value="1">Collect</option>
                <option value="2">Electronic transfer</option>
                <option value="3">Private</option>
                <option value="4">Cash</option>
            </select>
            <div class="errorTooltip errorTooltipRequired ng-binding ng-scope" id="etntavq">Verplicht</div>
            <label for="billingLine1" id="billingLine1Label" class="binding">Payment method</label>
            <div class="browse-btn" id="dropdown-btn">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
<style>
.Container .input, .Container .input option {
            height: 49px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0 14px;
            padding-top: 16px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border: 1px solid #c5ccd1;
            color: #000;
            -webkit-transition: border-color .3s ease 0s;
            transition: border-color .3s ease 0s;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: none;
            display: block;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }
 </style>
```

There is a second thing i want to be able to click a button and then automatically uncollapse the select field. I searched on stack but could find the right answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the default browser styling for the select input

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance : none;
}
```

See this response for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006590/5610732

Comment: Thank you that was it, I knew it had to be something simple. Couldn't find it