# Form Inputs Not Aligned

Tags: html, css

[image: Boxes not aligning]

[image: Input going out of bounds]

So I've come across an issue with my input box going out of bounds and I have no idea how to fix it. My select box and input box have the exact same CSS code. I've tried using max-width and vertical-align but both didn't work. Also tried using display: inline-block.

The difference between the 2 are exactly 4px even though both are set to 80% width

HTML

```
<form class="container_filterSelection">
    <label>Product Category</label>
    <select class="categorySelect">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Drills</option>
        <option value="2">More Drills</option>
        <option value="3">Give me them drills</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="locationSelect">
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</html>
```

CSS

```
form {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
}


/* Category Dropdown */

.categorySelect {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 16px 10%;
    padding: 16px 0;
}

/* Location Input */

.locationSelect {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10% 16px 10%;
    padding: 16px 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text Padding in Select Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006354/text-padding-in-select-boxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```css
form {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
}


/* Category Dropdown */

.categorySelect {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 16px 10% 16px 10%;
    padding: 16px 0;
}

/* Location Input */

.locationSelect {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10% 16px 10%;
    padding: 16px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form class="container_filterSelection">
    <label>Product Category</label>
    <select class="categorySelect">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Drills</option>
        <option value="2">More Drills</option>
        <option value="3">Give me them drills</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="locationSelect">
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.locationSelect` appears to fix it. The browser's user agent stylesheet appears to be adding this property to `select` elements but not to `input`, so to make them look the same, you need to correct for that.