# asp.net MVC 5 entity framework - DropDownListFor trims space?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have table of products with primary key(data type nvarchar(50)) like

`100531         00001`

in Model i get products List

```
public List<string> GetProductsList()
{
        List<string> productsList = new List<string>();
        using (Entities database = new Entities ())
        {
            productsList = (from product 
                            in database.Products
                            select product.ID).Take(10).ToList();

        }
        return productsList;
}
```

in View I display DropDownList with products

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product, new SelectList(Model.ProductsList), "-- Product --", new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

But items in DropDownList displays like

```
100531 00001
```

ID of product is also foreign key in Orders table. But I can't add new order with product ID
`100531 00001`

My question is : Can I change something in appliaction to display data like it is in database or I must change something in database?

UPDATE

found solution here [How to retain spaces in DropDownList - ASP.net MVC Razor views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828697/how-to-retain-spaces-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-razor-views)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")` method to preserve whitespaces in dropdownlistfor like following code.

Reference: http://www.dennisonpro.info/preserving-whitespace-in-dropdownlist-items-with-c-mvc-3/

```
public List<string> GetProductsList()
{
        List<string> productsList = new List<string>();
        using (Entities database = new Entities ())
        {
            productsList = (from product 
                            in database.Products
                            select product.ID).Take(10).ToList();

        }
        productsList = productsList.Select(str=>str.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
        return productsList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use key value pair list when you want to bind something to drop down list. Currently you are returning a list of string which hold product id but instead you should return a key value pair of either product id and product id or product id and product name. So that you can bind dropdown as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product, 
new SelectList(Model.ProductsList, "Key", "Value"), "-- Product --", 
new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

instead of your current implementation

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product, 
new SelectList(Model.ProductsList), "-- Product --", 
new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Problem with your current implementation is that you have multiple white space in your product id but html will allow only one white space character unless that is  . But in database you have white space character instead of &nbsp ; so while posting your data you get only 1 white space which doesn't match to your database record. Thus I recommend you to return key value pair of list.