# HTML: Consecutive spaces merged in option name in select

Tags: html

I want all of option name to be displayed as same length.
I have added &nbsp ; for padding for smaller length name. but browsers merged the cosnecutive spaces into one spaces.

```
<html>
<body>

<select name=\"test\" id=\"test\" >";
   <option value="None">Select</option>
   <option value="2"> ABCDEF&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dec09</option>
   <option value="3"> ABCDEFG&nbsp;&nbsp;Nov10</option>
   <option value="4"> ABCDEFGH&nbsp;Nov05</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752/how-do-i-put-a-space-character-before-option-text-in-a-html-select-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you even better: The spaces are as you say contracted when using simple spaces, so as you have noticed, using non-breaking spaces:   works better.
But you problem occurs because the width of a space is not the same as width other characters when using a default font, this is why a css property like

```
style="font-family:monospace;"
```

on your select-tag would ensure that spaces have the same width as any other character.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked.         <select style="font-family : monospace;">

Comment: Glad to hear that, please state that this was the answer to your question, but checking the check mark to the left of my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Give `width` to select, like:

```
<select name=\"test\" id=\"test\"  style="width:200px;">";
```

as per your requirement