# <s:select listValue="value" of struts2 is not getting all white spaces in "value"

Tags: struts2

I wrote s:select in struts in my jsp.  Here is my tag

```
 <s:select id="box1View" name="" listKey="productCode" listValue="%{getFormattedData(productCode,productName,category)}" list="availableRates" cssStyle="width: 100%; height: 150px; font-size: 10px; color: #000;" multiple="true" />
```

using getFormattedData() function I added whitespaces between productCode, productName and category to neatly format the data. Here is my getFormattedData function

```
public String getFormattedData(String productCode, String productName, String category) {
    productCode = StringUtils.rightPad(productCode, 10, ' ');
    productName = StringUtils.rightPad(productName, 25, ' ');
    category = StringUtils.rightPad(category, 10, ' ');
    String data= productCode+productName+category;
    System.out.println("data = "+ data);
    return data;
   }
```

when I was displayed using System.out.println I am getting the whitespaces added between productcode, prodctname and category but when the value of varaiable 'data' is showing using 'listValue' of  tag I am getting only one whitespace between productCode, productName and Category.   I need all whitespaces to properly align the data because I am showing the data of  data in a listbox.

Comment: Use plain `select` with `option`-s and see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25752/1700321.